# Separating Custom Template logic

Tags: shortcode, page-template

Our site displays athletic race results, and each runner has a specific wordpress user account. We have custom plugin to handle building the html elements. A specific runners page can be seen via this link

```
[http://bhaa.ie/runner/?id=7713][1]
```

I've implemented this page by using the wordpress custom template hook and the logic for rendering the page can be seen at this github link. There is a mix of presentation and business logic in the template. The custom template basically uses $_GET('id') to grab the runners id from the URL.

```
[https://github.com/emeraldjava/bhaawp/blob/master/public/views/runner.php][2]
```

I want to refactor the page, so that the business logic and layout are separated. I'd prefer that a UI design could work with a standard wordpress page, and use custom shortcodes to display the name, results and other elements that are specific to the user.

In my head, the UI design should be able to reference a simple shortcode such as

```
[bhaa_runner_results]
```

under the hood the logic for the shortcode can then grab the parameter value from the URL. If the UI designer want to include a specific runners results on the homepage they would just override the id attribute with a specific value

```
[bhaa_runner_results id="7713"]
```

the code would then use the 'shortcode_atts()' to extra the parameter value.

At the moment the 'id' value is passed as a GET parameter to the custom template but how i can access this 'id' value when the UI design is working on a standard page, such that it can be passed as a parameter to the shortcode. I've read that 'query_args' can be registered by a plugin but this seems overkill since i've not changing the main WP_Query. Is there a recommended standard pattern for wordpress plugins to register their own parameter names with the core wordpress API?

Comment: You could create a plugin or add the logic to the functions.php file.

Comment: Maybe it is only me, but I don't understand what is your question. It sounds like you are asking how to use $_GET in a shortcode.

Comment: Sorry - the question is vague. It feels like bad practice for the plugin/shortcode logic to use the $_GET to access this information. I've updated the question to ask is there a recommended way for plugins to define their own parameters.